# Yachol merosh chodesh - why not the day of the fifteenth?

Tags: midrash, passover-seder-hagada

We say in the Haggadah, quoted from the Mechilta:

> יָכוֹל מֵראשׁ חֹדֶשׁ? תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא. אִי בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא יָכוֹל מִבְּעוֹד יוֹם? תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר בַּעֲבוּר זֶה - בַּעֲבוּר זֶה לֹא אָמַרְתִּי, אֶלָּא בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁיֵּשׁ מַצָּה וּמָרוֹר מֻנָּחִים לְפָנֶיךָ.
>
> ‎It could be from Rosh Chodesh [that one would have to discuss the Exodus. However] we learn [otherwise, since] it is stated, "on that day." If it is [written] "on that day," it could be from while it is still day [before the night of the fifteenth of Nissan. However] we learn [otherwise, since] it is stated, "for the sake of this."  I didn't say 'for the sake of this' except [that it be observed] when [this] matsa and maror are resting in front of you [meaning, on the night of the fifteenth].

From [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah,_Magid,_Yechol_Me'rosh_Chodesh.1?lang=bi).

Why does the Haggadah not pose the option of saying it on the fifteenth? Why is that any less logical than the fourteenth?

Comment: The Pesach was already slaughtered on the 14th

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37716&st=&pgnum=148

Comment: The whole point is to see how early to start. Once the time is found, there is no need to delay it any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Malbim](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%97) explains that in this case, the night follows the day (presumably because with regard to kodashim/korban pesach, the night follows the day).

> ועל זה אמרו, יכול מראש חודש, תלמוד לומר ביום ההוא. וכבר בארתי בפ' אמור
>   ( אמור קלו ) שיש הבדל, שכל מקום שכתוב ביום ההוא- הלילה שייך אל היום
>   שלפניו. כמו ביום ההוא יאכל לא תותירו ממנו עד בקר. ועל זה אמר, אי ביום
>   ההוא יכול מבעוד יום כי היום שייך אל הלילה, לכן אמר בעבור זה.

See also the discussion by R. Shlomo Wahrman [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51883&st=&pgnum=114&hilite=).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @donie the issue is what is bayom hahu. If it's 15 Nissan then your question makes sense. This answer says the day is from sunrise 14 Nissan to sunrise 15 Nissan

Comment: @DoubleAA My question is why it *isn't* the 15th. All this does, then, is confirm the premise of my question.

Comment: @doni yes that is your question. The pasuk says bayom hahu, so there has to be another half day besides the night of the 15th where it's valid if not for baavur zeh. You'd think they should ask about 15 Nissan day. But they thought to ask about 14 Nissan day

Comment: @DoubleAA And the assumption of the ba'al Haggadah is that that day is the fourteenth and not the fifteenth. Why is that any more logical?

Comment: @doni no the assumption of the Haggadah is that day is from sunrise 14 Nissan to sunrise 15 Nissan. This answer explains that's because we're modeling after kodshim because of the korban Pesach

Comment: @donie because we're working in a kodhsim model. We're going in circles here...

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah. Now I get it.